# Solr Performance - how to OR a filter query with a regular query

Tags: solr

Trying to OR main query (q) and filter query (fq) using Solr 4.7.

We have a high frequency term in the index

```
'field1:value' - 5 million documents
'field2:value' - 500 documents which should be ranked higher
```

When searching by

```
q=field1:value OR field2:value
```

The query takes very long (more than 2 seconds)

When searching by

```
q=*:*fq=field1:value OR field2:value
```

The query runs rather fast, but I have no way to get the `field2:value` at the top of the list.

Currently post re-ranking is not an option.

I understand the speed of the filter query (fq) is that no scoring is involved. (This is not a frequent query, no caching is necessary).

Tried in the `QueryParser` plugin to wrap the `TermQuery` with a `ConstantScoreQuery`. 
But it seems performs just the same as an ordinary `TermQuery`.

What I am looking for is a way to run a filter query as an OR, what means `q=field2:value&or_fq=field2:value`
Or instead create a 'real-non-scoring' `TermQuery` within the main query.
Could you please help me? Thanks.

Comment: How about using `*:*` as the query, `field1:value` as the `fq`, and then using `field2:value` as the boost query (`bq` or `boost`)?

Comment: Great! What I actually need is `fq=field1:value OR field2:value`. (I believe it doesn't solve a more complex use case, but I didn't describe that case yet. Maybe I will soon edit the question). Thanks

Comment: That should work the same, so try to see if there's any difference in speed.

Comment: For the case I described above it works great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `*:*` as the query, then apply a filter query you did - `field1:value OR field2:value` as `fq`. You can then use `bq` or `boost` with `field2:value` to score those that have hits in `field2`.